# Searching and counting dictionary key value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dictionary

```
dict = {'brown dogs':3, 'dog of white':4, 'white cats':1, 'white cat':9}
```

How do I

a) search for key substrings

b) sum the values of those selected

So I get the result:

```
('dog', 7) and ('cat', 10)
```

Comment: `dict` is a keyword in python. i'd advise not to use it as a variable name (although it works of course)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'brown dogs':3, 'dog of white':4, 'white cats':1, 'white cat':9}
substrings = ['dog', 'cat']

counter = Counter()

for substring in substrings:
    for key in d:
        if substring in key:
            counter[substring] += d[key]

print(counter.items())
```

**Output:**

```
[('dog', 7), ('cat', 10)]
```

Answer (score 2):

With usage of dictionary for keeping subs:

```
dict = {'brown dogs':3, 'dog of white':4, 'white cats':1, 'white cat':9}
subs={'dog':0,'cat':0}
for sub in subs.keys():
    for k,v in dict.items():
        if sub in k:
            subs[sub]+=v
print(subs)->{'dog': 7, 'cat': 10}
```

But if You want to guess subs keys automatically it may be harder xD!

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution:

```
d = {'brown dogs':3, 'dog of white':4, 'white cats':1, 'white cat':9}
substrings = ['dog', 'cat']
my_list = [(substr, sum([d[key] for key in d.iterkeys() if substr in key])) for substr in substrings]
print my_list
```

**Output**

```
[('dog', 7), ('cat', 10)]
```

Comment: your 3rd line is cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a crack at it, since I need the practice!

```
mydict = {'brown dogs':3, 'dog of white':4, 'white cats':1, 'white cat':9}
mykeys = ['dog', 'cat', 'rhino']
sums_dict = {}
for mkey in mykeys:
    for dkey in mydict.keys():
        if mkey in dkey:
            try:
                sums_dict[mkey] += mydict[dkey]
            except KeyError:
                sums_dict[mkey] = mydict[dkey]
print(sums_dict)
```